# Multi-process support within the same app?

Tags: c#

Google Chrome and IE8 implement multi-process support for each tab.  How would I implement something like that using c# and vs2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... look up [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Then make your processes communcate with each other (e.g. passing data structures, commands, etc.). You will probably need a rendering process and a main process as well (or combine these  two into a single rendering/commanding process).